# Uso da ActionBar Up Navigation Android - API23

Tags: android, actionbar

Estou implementando um app que possui uma `activity` para carregar um mapa e outra `activity` para listar os lugares que o usuário selecionou no mapa.

Como estou trabalhando com a `API23`, a toolbar foi exibida com sucesso na `activity` principal.

**Preciso implementar o `up navigation` na `activity` dos mapas**, para que o usuário possa voltar a principal, se desejar. O problema é que não consigo usar `toolbar` nessa `activity` pq ela está herdando uma `FragmentActivity`, que não suporta o `setSupportActionBar`.

Sendo assim, tentei resolver criando manualmente uma `ActionBar` e por fim, atualizando o `Manifest`. Conforme imagem abaixo, não é exibido nada na ActionBar.

**Activity principal com ActionBar OK**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**MapsActivity com ActionBar sem nada**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Classe MapsActivity**

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.i("InfoLocalizacao", Integer.toString(intent.getIntExtra("InfoLocalizacao", -1)));

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Você precisa setar na tela dos mapas o botão voltar, certo? E o `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` simplesmente não funciona na sua FragmentActivity, correto?

Comment: @Luiz exatamente isso.

Comment: Troque `FragmentActivity` por `AppCompatActivity` e use `getSupportActionBar()` em vez de `getActionBar()`.

Comment: @Piovezan O problema é que preciso dar o `extend FragmentActivity` para os suportes ao mapa (conforme publiquei na minha questão). Como que eu consigo estender as duas?

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` já estende `FragmentActivity`, e com isso também inclui suporte aos mapas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque `FragmentActivity` por `AppCompatActivity` (que é uma subclasse de `FragmentActivity` com suporte à *action bar*).

Assim, além de poder trabalhar com mapas na sua `MapsActivity`, terá acesso à *action bar* através do método `getSupportActionBar()` (que deverá ser usado no lugar de `getActionBar()`).

Para isso será preciso usar a biblioteca **appcompat** de suporte versão 7 ([veja aqui como instalar](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/support-library/setup.html)).

---

**(EDITADO)** Veja se o seu styles.xml está parecido com esse:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Veja também se funciona sem os `<item>`. Talvez funcione sem.

Comment: Editei a classe `MapsActivity` da minha pergunta, com as novas alterações sugeridas. O problema é que está dando `FATAL EXCEPTION` ao acessar a classe - `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se resolve o problema. Qualquer dúvida, poste o seu styles.xml.

Comment: Bingo, tive que alterar o styles.xml. Muito Obrigado. Abraços.